# Add my own news feed to my app

Tags: java, android, rss-reader, feed

There isn't much detail to say. Basically, i want to add news feed when the app is opened (yes i the java part), but i don't want to parse any website or something, i want to be able to create my own articles and publish them to the app every few days.

I have no idea how to do this or what to look for. I though of creating my own RSS site and then use it in the app, but i don't know if it's a good idea or if there are better ways of doing this. I probably need to do web programming, if so, where do i start ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're better start off creating some `Web Service`s or `API`s which would get your articles from a source like `SQL Database` or something similar, convert it to some easily parsable format (`JSON` I recommend) and send it to the client, then in your android app you should query your previously mentioned `API`s, parse and deserialize them to be used and shown by Android app.